# Find and print duplicates in a complex JSON array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net, for-loop

Am trying to figure out and print the duplicates from a complex nested JSON array using C# in .NET.

I want to check if the value **"title"** is duplicated and there is also a nested JSON array *(items)* that has the values: **title** and **value** in which I want to check the duplicates.

So, the values: **title** and **value** of the nested array should be compared with those of the other nested array values. The **outer "title"** should be checked with the outer one.

*id and sourceId should be ignored*

Tried to do it with foreach but couldn't get into the nested array using the . (dot).
then tried with for loop but I got lost.

As an outcome, I want to print the duplicated values.

*Could you help me?*

An overview of how the JSON array looks like is as follow

```
{
    "id": "0789a960-45de-11ea-ae56-23ecd3bd0e35",
    "sourceId": "6e009cc0-fc83-11e9-8fb9-01af70ec8d3f",
    "title": "Glass-reinforced concrete (GRC) built-in quoins",
    "items": [{
        "title": "Description",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Manufacturer",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Height (overall)",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Applied surface finish",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Applied finish colour",
        "value": ""
    }]
}, {
    "id": "0a607010-45de-11ea-ae56-23ecd3bd0e35",
    "sourceId": "73a96f31-fc83-11e9-8fb9-01af70ec8d3f",
    "title": "Clay bricks",
    "items": [{
        "title": "Description",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Manufacturer",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Standard",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Brick description",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Execution",
        "value": ""
    }]
}, {
    "id": "0ce40db0-45de-11ea-ae56-23ecd3bd0e35",
    "sourceId": "73a96f31-fc83-11e9-8fb9-01af70ec8d3f",
    "title": "Clay bricks",
    "items": [{
        "title": "Description",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Manufacturer",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Standard",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Appearance",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "title": "Execution",
        "value": ""
    }]
},  ............. and so on
```

Comment: You haven't posted valid JSON, are these items in an array?

Comment: Also, what output are you expecting? The above 3 items are all different according to your description, right?

Comment: @DavidG this is an example of a complex JSON array, just to illustrate how it looks.
in case there are duplicate values I want to print them.

Comment: @DavidG if it helpes something similar could be this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXV19.png

Comment: Where is your attempt to solve a problem?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski as described i tried with foreach and for but messed it up. could not come up with a solution. this is the link https://dotnetfiddle.net/sln3wH in which i tried to solve that problem. could you have a look at this?

Comment: Well, that is not your code on dotnetfiddle, I know because it was written by someone I know, so if you could perhaps be more honest with us, then we might just help you.

Comment: @DavidG I did not say is my code. and it is good that you know who might have written it. However, as long as it is online I guess whoever uploaded, had the intentions to let coders exercise with that. if had not that intensions I assume it would not be public. if you wish to provide help to understand how to solve a problem like this you are welcome. thanks in advance

Comment: You just said you tried with a foreach and then linked us the code, but you haven't shown us what you tried. Also, my answer gives you exactly what you need and it pretty similar to that link.

Comment: Hi @DavidG I did not say that your answer is not good. it is good and explanatory. However, I am looking for a more simple solution like for loop or foreach if that is possible, as my background is not from Computer science.

Comment: Sometimes there isn't a simple answer. The code I wrote though, it's pretty simple once you understand it.

Comment: @DavidG the reason I said that a for loop or a foreach could be simpler is that from a short discussion I had I've been told that could be solved with for loop in order to get into each complex JSON array. However, when i tried either using foreach or for loop i couldn't manage it.
anyway i would like to thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to convert the above JSON into C# objects to hold the properties you are deserialising, for example:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<TitleValue> Items { get; set; }
}

public class TitleValue
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // This is needed later for the comparer
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 31 + Title.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 31 + Value.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can deserialise into a list of items like this:

```
// If you are using Newtonsoft JSON.Net:
var things = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Thing>>(jsonString);

// If you are using System.Text.Json:

var settings = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};

var things = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Thing>>(jsonString, settings);
```

The next thing you can make is a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Thing>` that you can pass into a Linq `GroupBy`. For example:

```
public class ThingEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Thing>
{
    public bool Equals(Thing x, Thing y)
    {
        if (!x.Title.Equals(y.Title))
            return false;

        if (x.Items.Count() != y.Items.Count())
            return false;

        foreach (var item in x.Items)
        {
            if (!y.Items.Any(otherItem => otherItem.Title.Equals(item.Title) && 
                                          otherItem.Value.Equals(item.Value)))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Thing obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 31 + obj.Title.GetHashCode();
            foreach (var item in obj.Items)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + item.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can run some Linq queries, such as:

```
var thingCounts = things
    .GroupBy(t => t, new ThingEqualityComparer())
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        Thing = g.Key, 
        Count = g.Count() 
    });
```

And if you want to find duplicates in that list you can filter them with a `Where` clause:

```
var duplicateThingCounts = thingCounts.Where(tc => tc.Count > 1)
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the duplicates, such as print them out however you like:

```
foreach (var thingCount in duplicateThingCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(thingCount.Thing.Title);
}
```

Comment: could you check this link that has the online editor ? https://dotnetfiddle.net/sln3wH

Comment: What do you want me to do with that link?

Comment: is the online editor .net fiddle where i tried to solve the problem I described in this post. by reading that may better understand my point of view.